# JavaCC grammar conflict

Tags: parsing, parser-generator, javacc

I have a grammar defined roughly like this.

```
TOKEN:{
        <T_INT: "int"> |
        <T_STRING: ["a"-"z"](["a"-"z"])*>
}

SKIP: { " " | "\t" | "\n" | "\r" }

/** Main production. */
SimpleNode Start() : {}
{
        (LOOKAHEAD(Declaration()) Declaration() | Function())
  { return jjtThis; }
}

void Declaration() #Decl: {}
{
        <T_INT> <T_STRING> ";"
}

void Function() #Func: {}
{
        <T_STRING> "();"
}
```

This works fine for stuff like:

```
int a;
foo();
```

But when I try `int();`, which is legal for me and should be parsed by the Function(), it goes for the Declaration instead. How do I fix this "conflict"? I tried various combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaCC FAQ's section on this is titled "[How do I deal with keywords that aren't reserved](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-FAQ/javacc-faq-moz.htm#tth_sEc4.19)?".

What I would do is allowing the keywords alternatively to the identifiers, i.e.

```
(<T_STRING> | <T_INT>) "();"
```

When there are many keywords, it could be beneficial to create an `Identifier` production that allows them all, along with the general identifier token.

By the way, you might want `"(" ")" ";"` instead of `"();"`.